# writing C program that goes off after 10 seconds

Tags: c, signals, interrupt

I want to write a C program that runs for a specified amount of seconds
say 10 seconds and then exits. The code should set up an interrupt to go 
off after a specified amount of time has elapsed.

Here is my attempt. But I am not sure if SIGALRM is the correct way to do it.
Can SIGALRM be called an interrupt?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void handler()
{
    _exit(0);
}
int main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, handler);
    alarm(10);
    for (;;);  /* You can assume that for(;;); is just a dummy code. The main idea is to insert something into code. Whatever code it may be so that it stops after 10 seconds –  */
        return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions/alternatives/better way to achieve this?

Comment: `return 0;` is bad indented. and I will use `for (;;) sleep(1);`  in order to avoid consuming the whole CPU.

Comment: You can assume that for(;;); is just a dummy code. The main idea is to insert something into code. Whatever code it may be so that it stops after 10 seconds

Comment: @nishaaunty Please [edit] your question to add clarification instead of answering in comments. I suggest to add a comment to the loop with the explanation from your comment.

Comment: suggest using: `setitimer()` see the man page for details

Comment: @user3629249, unfortunately, the convenient `setitimer` [is obsolescent](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html#tag_16_202_14).  `alarm` or `timer_settime` will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

The wording "signal" vs. "interrupt" is not fully clear. Signals can interrupt system calls, so a signal is an interrupt in this sense. But a signal is not a hardware interrupt. Whan you use an operating system, normal programs often don't have direct access to hardware interrupts.

Calling `_exit` from the signal handler might be problematic if your program needs to finish a task or to clean up something.

I suggest to implement a graceful end by setting a flag. Additionally I suggest to use `sigaction` instead of `signal`, because the semantics of `signal` and signal handlers set up with this function is implementation-dependent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t timeout = 0;

void handler(int sig)
{
    (void) sig;
    timeout = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = handler;
    if(sigaction(SIGALRM, act, NULL) < 0)
    {
        // handle error
    }
    alarm(10);
    while(!timeout /* and maybe other conditions */)
    {
        // do something, handle error return codes and errno (EINTR)
        // check terminate flag as necessary
    }

    // clean up if necessary

    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation** (as requested in a comment)

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t timeout = 0;
```

`sig_atomic_t` is a type that guarantees atomic access even in the presence of asynchronous interrupts made by signals. That means an access to the variable cannot be interrupted in between, i.e. the software will never see a partially modified value. (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t)

`volatile` informs the compiler not to optimize access to the variable. This is necessary because the signal handler may modify the value while the main function is running the loop that is intended to check the flag. Otherwise the compiler might optimize the access out of the loop condition and do it only once before the loop because the variable is never modified inside the loop. (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile)